# How can i add a two datetimepicker in visual basic and display in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to my project. if a put on a message box it will work and display how many days but if in a text box wasn't working.

```
If True Then
    Dim dt1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text)
    Dim dt2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)

    If Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days) >= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Total Days are " & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Show your code to clarify exactly what is not working.

Comment: If True Then
            Dim dt1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text)
            Dim dt2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text)
            Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)
            If Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days) >= 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Total Days are " & Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input")
            End If
        End If

Comment: i want to display with a text box not in a message box

Comment: First of all, why are you picking text from `DateTimePicker` and then again converting it again to DateTime ?

Use `DateTimePicker1.Value` to retrieve value.

Comment: Also, it is redundant to call `Convert.ToInt32(ts.Days)`.  `ts.Days` is _already_ an Int32 and doesn't need to be converted.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or set it in your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this won't work... If it doesn't provide us with the error you're getting

```
If True Then
    Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)

    If ts.Days >= 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = ts.Days
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Invalid Input"
    End If
End If
```